# Complex multi row aggregate SQL query

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions

I'm looking for a way to aggregate by the existence of the same foreign keys across multiple rows.

E.g., ID numbers 1 and 2 should be aggregated together because they both have the same exact foreign keys across all rows, whereas ID number 3 does not have the same foreign keys across all rows, so it should be separate.

Note:  Using DB2

Example source data:

```
ID  QUANTITY    COLOR
1   10          BLUE
1   10          RED
1   10          GREEN
2   30          BLUE
2   30          RED
2   30          GREEN
3   15          GREEN
3   15          YELLOW
```

Desired result set:

```
TEMP_ID     SUMQTY  COLOR
1           40      BLUE
1           40      RED
1           40      GREEN
2           15      GREEN
2           15      YELLOW
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: Where is that "*same foreign key*" in your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to find out if the "colors" for two "ids" are the same.  The following query does a full outer join on `color`, and then aggregates by `id`.  If two `id`s have the same color, then the full outer join always matches -- there are no NULLs:

```
select s1.id, s2.id
from s s1 full outer join
     s s2
     on s1.color = s2.color
group by s1.id, s2.id
having sum(case when s1.color is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       sum(case when s2.color is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Using the same idea, we can assign the minimum s1.id as the "id" of the group.  This group id then gives us the information needed for the final aggregation:

```
select s3.groupid, sum(s3.quantity) as quantity, s3.color as color
from (select min(s1.id) as groupid, s2.id
      from (select s1.id, s2.id
            from s s1 full outer join
                 s s2
                 on s1.color = s2.color
            group by s1.id, s2.id
            having sum(case when s1.color is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
                   sum(case when s2.color is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
           ) ss
      group by s2.id
     ) sg join
     s s3
     on sg.id = s.id
group by sg.groupid, s3.color
```

In DB2 you can also do this with `listagg`.  First you need to get the list of colors to identify commonality, and then use it:

```
select min(s.id) as groupid, sum(s.quantity) as quantity, s.color
from (select id, listagg(color order by color) as thegroup
      from s
      group by id
     ) sg join
     s
     on sg.id = s.id
group by sg.thegroup, s.color
```

This is probably more efficient than the first solution.

Comment: thank you!  Brilliant use of the full outer join and also good call on the LISTAGG function!